# How to get Link url (href) stored in <li> in WebDriver using java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i have an html source like this;

```html
<ul class="menu">
<li class="submenuitem">
<a title="" href="/mysite/planning">Planning</a>
</li>
<li class="submenuitem">
<a title="" href="/mysite/planning-system">Planning System</a>
</li>
<li class="submenuitem">
<a title="" href="/mysite/planning/partners"> Planning Partners</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

I want to get all href urls below in every "li" tag using selenium web driver in Java.
I tried the following code below;

```
List<WebElement> links =driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("submenuitem"));
        for (int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++)
        {
            links.getindex(i).getAttribute("href")
        }
```

But links.getAttribute("href") is returning null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `By.cssSelector("submenuitem")`, it should be
`By.cssSelector(".submenuitem")` or `By.className("submenuitem")`

Another way could be

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[href*='/mysite']"));
```

That will give you all the `href` which contains `"/mysite"`

Comment: yes you are right  i should use `By.cssSelector(".submenuitem")` to laocate items But `links.get(i).getAttribute("href")` is still showing null

Comment: That's because the `href` is in `a`, not `li`

Comment: so is there a way to get the href only below ` <li> `element :(  i am new to web driver and do not find the solution for this.

Comment: Try driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".submenuitem > "));

Comment: That should give you all the `a` elements.

Comment: `driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".submenuitem > "))` is showing  **invalid selector exception**

Comment: Sorry, `driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".submenuitem > a"))`